# How to load JSON number values set as string in angular?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, expression

I cannot seen to be able to load in a json image if the key value is a number, it doesn't seem to matter if I call it in html text or ascii.

Here I use two different key `foo` and `200x150` that have the same image value

**json:**

```
$scope.items = [
       {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Location 1",
          "items_image": {
            "id": 101,
            "image": {
              "200x150": "http://placehold.it/200x150?text=num1",
              "foo":     "http://placehold.it/200x150?text=foo1"
            }
          }
        }
```

**loading foo as "foo":** works

```
<img ng-src="{{item.items_image.image.foo}}">
```

**loading foo as "`&#102;&#111;&#111;`":** works

```
 <img ng-src="{{item.items_image.image.&#102;&#111;&#111;}}">
```

**loading 200x150 as "200x150":** fails

```
<img ng-src="{{item.items_image.image.200x150}}">
```

**loading 200x150 as "`&#50;&#48;&#48;&#120;&#49;&#53;&#48;`":** fails

```
<img ng-src="{{item.items_image.image.&#50;&#48;&#48;&#120;&#49;&#53;&#48;}}">
```

How do I do this with numbers? I included an example: http://codepen.io/garrettmac/pen/wKOmoP

Comment: Can you use array notation? `items.items_image.image['200x150']` -- I'm not sure if JavaScript object keys can begin with a number, but it's apparently valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

```
<img ng-src="{{item.items_image.image['200x150']}}">
```